# How to set up logitech media server on raspberry pi (squeezebox server)?

Tags: media-server, raspbian-buster

I wanted to set up logitech media server on my raspberry pi as a server for my music collection as well as for my favorite web radio stations with the option to synchronize several Squeezeboxes in my home.

I run a freshly installed Raspbian Buster which is 32bit, although the Raspberry is a 64bit chip.

Answer (score 1):

Download Raspbian Buster from [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_full_latest). Extract the ZIP to get an IMG. Install the IMG to a SD card with [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download) on Windows - if you use Windows. After the installation is complete, put a file on the boot partition that is named just `ssh` to activate SSH login. Log into the Raspi using [Putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html) with username `pi` and password `raspberry`. Change your password with `passwd pi`.

Do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.

---

Download current stable or nightly version **arm.deb** with `wget`. (I tried with last stable version 7.9.1 and was not able to reach the webGUI, that's why I recommend 7.9.2 nightly).

**UPDATE: In general, all versions can be found [here](http://downloads.slimdevices.com/nightly/index.php). For RaspberriPi the `arm` architecture is necessary. This is the file you want to download with `wget`.**

---

Install it with `dpkg -i arm.de`. It will fail with missing dependencies.

Install missing dependencies and complete installation with `apt --fix-broken install`.

During that process the following packages will be installed:

```
libio-socket-ssl-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl perl-openssl-defaults
```

Connect to the web-gui of LMS with a browser: `IP:9000`.

Voilá!

If you don't get a connection with the browser check if the Raspberry is listing to ports 9000, 9090 and 3483 with `netstat -t -l`. Output should be like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3483            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

Comment: The link [arm.deb](http://downloads.slimdevices.com/nightly/7.9/sc/3765a9f7d34fe653b5029392a972ec064e994acc/logitechmediaserver_7.9.2~1564788734_arm.deb) is broken: *The requested URL /nightly/7.9/sc/3765a9f7d34fe653b5029392a972ec064e994acc/logitechmediaserver_7.9.2~1564788734_arm.deb was not found on this server.*

Comment: Thank you.
But the URL arm.db is broken. Can you fix it ?
Maybe we can use 8.1 version from now? Regard.
Pierre

Comment: I removed the actual link from my answer. Please see the remaining link and find the most recent version folder (currently 8.1). It will be easy to pick the correct file from my answer's description. @pierre Also, please consider upvoting if an answer helped you.